# Aggregate Group by using minimum value and display count for each group at MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, minimum

I have a table ProdTable with following content:
ProdName    PrdCategory PrdPrice
PrdB         34         8
PrdA         34         50
PrdC         134        49
PrdC         134        50
PrdD         34         8

I want to receive the output from MongoDB Collection (same content)
ProdCategory    min(PrdPrice)   count
34               8               2
134              49              1

How will I write my db.ProdTable.Aggregate?

Comment: In SQL, I got what I want with this query. " select  ProdName, min(PrdPrice), count(*) from ProdTable
group by ProdCategory 
order by PrdPrice, PrdCategory
"

Comment: Got answered from Duncan. Here is the answer:

db.products.aggregate([
  { $group: { _id: "$ProdCategory", minPrice: { $min: "$ProdPrice" }, prices: { $push: "$ProdPrice" } } }, 
  { $unwind: "$prices" }, 
  { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$prices", "$minPrice"] } } }, 
  { $group: { _id: "$_id", minPrice: { $min: "$minPrice" }, count: { $sum: 1 } } } 
])

And my expected answer works like a charm, as shown below! Thanks Duncan.
[
  { _id: 134, minPrice: 49, count: 1 },
  { _id: 34, minPrice: 8, count: 2 }
]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
db.products.aggregate([
   { $group: { _id: "$ProdCategory", minPrice: { $min: "$ProdPrice" }, prices: { $push: "$ProdPrice" } } }, 
   { $unwind: "$prices" }, 
   { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$prices", "$minPrice"] } } }, 
   { $group: { _id: "$_id", minPrice: { $min: "$minPrice" }, count: { $sum: 1 } } } 
])

And my expected answer works like a charm, as shown below! Thanks Duncan.
 [
   { _id: 134, minPrice: 49, count: 1 },
   { _id: 34, minPrice: 8, count: 2 }
 ]
```